# Is there any case of total transmission?

Tags: optics, visible-light

When light strikes the interface of two media some light is refracted and some is reflected. But, is there a case where no light is reflected i.e all the light gets passed through the given object.

My thoughts: For thinking about this situation I should have a minimum knowledge on how light must strike an interface for total transmission of light. But, I'm afraid I don't know about it.So, please help if there is such a specific situation where no light is reflected but transmitted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special case where there is 100% transmission and no reflection.

First, the incoming light must be TM polarized (with the magnetic field parallel to the surface and electric field in the plane common to the incoming ray and the surface normal vector).

Second, the second medium must be optically denser than the first medium.

Then, there is a certain angle, called [Brewster's angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle), which if the incident light approaches at this angle, there will be 100% transmission at the interface.

**Edit**

> But, why does that happen?

There's two ways to look at it.

1. The [Fresnel equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) give the reflection amplitude as a function of incident angle. The Brewster angle is the angle at which the equation for TM- (aka *p-*) polarized light goes to zero.
2. If we solve the wave equations for a plane wave incident on a dielectric boundary, there is a required boundary condition that the tangential component of the E-field and H-field be continuous at the boundary. The Brewster angle is the angle at which this boundary condition can be achieved without requiring the presence of a reflected wave.

Comment: But, why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible cases of total transmission at an interface (assuming that the media are lossless), and below is a list of the underlying physics:

- if the media are impedance matched any the given incidence angle. Brewster's angle can be seen as a special case. Usually, at normal incidence, this condition would require the materials to have the same refractive indices. One can also use metamaterial to achieve total transmission across a material interface of different refractive indices.
- if the excited electric dipoles cannot radiate backwards. Microscopically, reflection occurs because the incident light excites electric dipoles which then reradiate and generate the reflection. Brewster's angle is again a special case.
- if multiple contributions to the reflection destructively interfere and completely cancel. This is often achieved, for example, by using an optical resonance at the interface.
- if the interface is nanostructured to provide adiabatic impedance transition. This can be approximately and robustly achieved by graded index.